# How to have a logo and institute at the same line?

Tags: beamer, titles

I would like to have the logo to the left and the institute to the right at the same line.

And so, I have tried unsuccessfully the code below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
    \institute{\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{oxfordunilogo.jpg}
\hspace*{4.75cm}}, School of Mathematics}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
     \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    ABC
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does `\institute{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{oxfordunilogo} \hspace*{4.75cm} School of Mathematics}` work?

Comment: The `Copenhagen` theme does not insert `\titlegraphic` - which you have only defined locally - into the `\institute`. Try @samcarter's suggestion or add `\inserttitlegraphic` after `\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{oxfordunilogo.jpg}`.

Comment: @samcarter Yes, it does. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting previous comment into an answer:

The easiest way is probably to just insert the logo in the institute. In case you use the `\institute` field in other places like the footline, this might mess with the formatting, but this can be easily solved by giving a short version, too.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\institute[short version]{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{oxfordunilogo} \hspace*{4.75cm} School of Mathematics}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
        ABC
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```